# How does glBufferData know which VBO to work on?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Here is the formal declaration for `glBufferData` which is used to populate a VBO:

`void glBufferData(GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid* data, GLenum usage);`

What is confusing, however, is that you can have multiple VBOs, but this function does not require a handle to a particular VBO, so how does it know which VBO you are intending?

The `target` parameter can be either `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` or `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` but my understanding is that you can have more than one of each of these.

The same is true of the similar `glBufferSubData` method, which is intended to be called subsequent times on a VBO -- how does it know which VBO to handle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it necessary to bind a buffer more than once in succession?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172206/why-is-it-necessary-to-bind-a-buffer-more-than-once-in-succession)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but answering the one, answers the other

Comment: if it's not really a duplicate, it shouldn't voted to close as a duplicate. You also can't assume the asker sees a direct relationship between two different questions. You are a harsh man, downvoting 2 legitimate questions.

Comment: It looks like OpenGL version 4.5 introduces a glNamedBufferData

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [common pattern in OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object) to bind object to a target and perform operations on it by issuing function calls without a handle. The same applies to the textures.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL operations that use a buffer object, make use of the buffer that has been bound by the most recent call to glBindBuffer on the used target.

Answer (score 0):

`glBindBuffer` is a function that exposes the given buffer as bound. Such a `glBufferData` access it then by side-effect, through the currently bound buffer object.