# Why is it necessary to bind a buffer more than once in succession?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does glBufferData know which VBO to work on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172165/how-does-glbufferdata-know-which-vbo-to-work-on)

I've noticed in sample code (in an O'Reilly book) for both VBOs and render buffers that the binding is done more than once. What is the reasoning behind this?  For example, you might have this at the top of an OpenGL routine:

```
  glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBuffer); 
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
```

And then before doing the drawing, you do it again:

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer); 
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
  //on to the drawing routine
```

Removing either of these causes the drawing to not appear, so why does it need binding twice?

Another example first we do this:

```
// Create & bind the color buffer so that the caller can allocate its space.      
   glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &m_colorRenderbuffer); 
   glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_colorRenderbuffer);
```

Then, after creating vertices, etc, we later we do it again:

```
   // Bind the color buffer for rendering. 
      glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, m_colorRenderbuffer);
```

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but answering the one question, answers the other.

Comment: if it's not really a duplicate, it shouldn't voted to close as a duplicate. You also can't assume the asker sees a direct relationship between two different questions.

Comment: You noticed yourself, that if you omit binding a buffer before doing the drawing operations things would not work. So something about the bind process makes OpenGL know what to use. IMHO it's a very simple and obvious mental connection to make. The vote for close is, because one of the two questions is redundant, and one of them should be closed.

Comment: Arrogance. "In my opinion, it's a very simple and obvious mental connection to make." I suppose you've never asked a question of someone who knew more than you and found the concept simple while you found it confusing? Never?

Comment: I'd like to put it that way: I did learn programming (and OpenGL), when there were no tutorials around, where you had to figure out things for yourself either by trying, or reading the specification documents, or by, well, inference. Of course I went asking around, but I'd normally do some research first and only ask when I was so stuck that I'd see no way out. Finding out what glBindBuffer does, or how glVertexPointer/glVertexAttribPointer interact with buffer objects doesn take more effort than reading their reference documentation.

Comment: The point is, people giving answers on forums like StackOverflow feel bullshitted, if they're confronted with questions so simple that they add no real value to the whole site. In information theory there's the concept of signal-to-noise-ration. Your signal (question) is noise to everybody else not interested in that question. Assume everyone of SO would ask trivial questions without doing their own research first: The whole site would be just trivial noise and the really interesting questions, that in fact require some effort to answer get obstructed by this noise.

Comment: The OpenGL API is quite complicated. "Stupid" questions are easy when dealing with complicated matters, and to those with the experience in these complicated matters, what seems "stupid" to them is just part of a very challenging learning curve for many others. Your arrogance lies in acknowledging that at least 1 of my 2 questions was valid, yet voting to close them both, and for a reason that you also stated isn't accurate, as they are not duplicates. To me, your responses here have been NOISE.

Comment: I voted both to close because of their circular dependency. One of them may remain open, and I'd say it is the question on this page. Alas, the OpenGL API is not very complicated. In my opinion it's one of the APIs most easily to comprehend. You want to look at a complicated API? Then look at OpenSSL, then we can talk about "APIs being complicated".

Comment: Okay, if you make a small edit (just adding a whitespace, or changing some word) so that I can change my vote, I'm going to redact my downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** necessary to bind the same buffer more than once in succession. It is enough to do it once. In your sample with array buffer, drawing might not appear if you are making a binding to another (or a default 0) buffer before drawing routine.

Comment: Well, in any OpenGL program that goes beyond drawing a single, simple object, in other words anything other than a tutorial, you'll have to switch between buffer objects serveral times throughout rendering a frame. So saying "it's not neccesary" is same as saying "Oh, you don't have to drink water, as long as we're only assuming this afternoon."

Comment: @datenwolf, "it is not necessary ... in succession".

Comment: Well, somewhere in OPs program the buffer binding gets changed, otherwise removing any but the first call to glBindBuffer would have no effect. OP didn't state if those calls happend in succession or not. Assuming a generic situation they probably happen at different places of the program.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd have waited for answers of your question [How does glBufferData know which VBO to work on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172165/how-does-glbufferdata-know-which-vbo-to-work-on)
this question had been answered as well.

OpenGL is a state machine and calls to glBindBuffer select, which buffer the following operations do work on.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: I'm not karma/reputation whoring :) Also I'm not mean, I'm blunt. I'm now programming computers for over 23 years and I found that the only way to get things communicated is to be, well, blunt.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Ever read how Linus Torvalds is talking/writing to people on the Linux Kernel Mailing List? I love him for being so open and direct. Everytime somebody comes along with a really stupid thing people like Andrew Morton or GKH try to explain it in a diplomatic way. Most of the time to no avail. Then Linus steps in, rants into everybodys general direction and usually gets across the point.

Comment: Ok. I see you are comparing yourself to Linus Torvalds. What works for one person doesn't work everyone.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: No I'm not comparing myself to the Big L. I just think that the way he deals with those things is the one that works best. It's not perfect, it's not conservative on the emotions of others, but when we're talking about technical things, what do we care about emotions? You asked two very similar questions (hint, they both have the words "buffer" in them and are tagged "opengl"), without *waiting* if maybe the answer to the one could shed light on the other. That's not how to figure things out.